# Установка кодировки без атрибута charset

Tags: utf-8, xhtml

Добрый день,

Есть сайты (например http://www.selmashbank.ru/), если смотреть в исходный код страницы там нет ни одного упоминания UTF !!! Если берем проверку http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/check?uri=www.selmashbank.ru%2F#validate-by-uri+ Пишет "HTTP Content-Type     utf-8   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" почему происходит такое издевательство ? Изучил все доступные поисковые запросы кодировка устанавливается либо charset= либо encoding= однако на этом сайте так же как на 10-ках других НЕТ даже слова utf тем не менее все браузеры СРАЗУ определяют его как UTF ? В чем секрет ? Возможно Xhtml - означает только UTF8?
Мне нужно определять кодировку для чужих сайтов, любое url которое введет пользователь. Стандартное средство PHP всегда выдает результат utf-8 даже на те страницы которые в 1251.
Для этого я начал анлизировать charset и encoding, но на страницах где этих тегов нет, я ничего не могу определить, но ИнтeрнeтЕксрлорер или ФаирФокс ВСЕГДА правильно определяют эти страницы ! В чем секрет и как определить кодировку на PHP если нет заветных слов charset encoding???

Answer (score 1):

Да, в самой странице кодировки нет, и в большинстве случаев браузеры в тексте страницы ее и не смотрят. Когда сервер передает вам страницу по протоколу HTTP то перед текстом страницы идут заголовки HTTP. Вот в них и находится кодировка, на которую в первую очередь смотрят браузеры и другие программы, вроде вашего валидатора.

Например, если вы получаете страницу средствами curl, то `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);` в том числе даст и кодировку. Поищите в своем средстве работы с HTTP способ получения заголовков.

Comment: Спасибо, что задали правильное направление, но хочу спросить есть ли что по проще как получить этот заголовок ? Я получаю текст странички = file_get_contents('google.com') а curl требует создавать дескриптор, вызвать, проверять и т.д. вобщем много канители ... есть на PHP что-то попроще =ФункцияПолучитьЗаголовок(URL) ?

Comment: Огромное спасибо со всем разобрался !

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно настройть веб серве Nginx/Apache на отдачу документа в нужной кодировке.

1. http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html
2. А если у Вас Apache, то можно добавить вот это в файлик .htaccess в корневой папке с сайтом:

   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: Для своего сайта все понятно, вопрос в том как узнать для ЧУЖЕГО сайта кодировку если формально в исходном коде страницы нет вообще слова charset или encoding, например я создаю для тренировки свой браузер в PHP как мне правильно отразить в нем странички по url? почему все браузеры однозначно определяют точно кодировку ? Что они анализируют на странице ? Как это реализовать на PHP?